# Date Picker is Not Appearing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to get a date picker to appear using Jquery UI's datepicker and a custom initializer.  I've uploaded the code to JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/f1c6j3fa/ but just can't figure it out why it's not working.

```
Anyone have any ideas?
```

Thanks

Comment: While the jsfiddle link is helpful, please post the code here.

Comment: ok, that's strange. i can't get it to work in this JSFiddle either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using reserved css class `.hasDatepicker` which prevents datepicker's show